# Fresh install of 14.04 LTS without disturbing Windows

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I have a dual-boot system with an end-of-life version of Ubuntu and Windows Vista 64.  I want to replace the old Ubuntu with 14.04 LTS, without disturbing the Windows setup.  How do I do this?  (Please explain in lay language...)

Answer (score 0):

Goto to Ubuntu.com website and download the desktop version of the current OS. It will download the iso image of the OS.

Start up the DVD burning software that you use and burn the iso image to the DVD (I believe the OS is too large to fit on a CD now).

Restart the computer from the DVD you created and follow instructions.

For the flash drive, you need to convert the iso file. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/191054/how-to-create-bootable-usb-drives-and-sd-cards-for-every-operating-system/) is an outline of the process.
Windows would use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create the USB bootable image.
Ubuntu would use [Startup Disk Creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) or [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net).
Set the BIOS to boot from USB and reboot.

Comment: I tried to follow your directions.  I downloaded 14.04LTS and got a long so file.  Then I tried to burn that to a DVD+R, but got an error message about a checksum.  I tried the same thing again, to another DVD+R, but got the same error message.  (I have long log files from each attempt.)  Then I tried to copy the iso file to a flash drive.  This worked, but I have no idea how to "restart the computer from" this flash drive, any more than I would have had from the DVD I would have created.

Comment: Which software are you using to create DVDs?

Comment: I used brasero to try to burn the iso file to a DVD.  Then I simply copied the iso file to a FAT32-formatted flash drive, but I have no idea how to boot the computer using that.  Do I have to change something in the BIOS so it knows to look at the flash drive first?  Or do I first have to modify the copied iso file?

Comment: I think there might have been an error in the download process so the file was written incorrectly (although the process is suppose to prevent errors). You could try downloading the OS into a different directory and compare the 2 files.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try that.  But assuming that wasn't the case, how would I boot the computer from the flash-drive copy of the iso file?

Comment: I just re-downloaded the iso file: it's identical to the one I tried to use before.  So maybe there's something wrong with my DVD writer.  Anyway, I give up on trying the DVD route.  Now how do I go by way of the stick?

Comment: I've change my answer above to help you use the USB drive.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get understand.  The Universal USB Installer seems to be a Windows (.exe) program.  How would I run it on my Ubuntu machine?  (Or is there some other source, besides Pendrivelinux.com, that's for Ubuntu?)

Comment: Sorry about that, I was not paying attention. On the first page it states `You can use similar tools on Linux. For example, Ubuntu includes a Startup Disk Creator tool for creating bootable Ubuntu USB drives. UNetbootin also runs on Linux, so you can use that too.` I've added the links above.

Comment: Great -- I didn't realize that I could use the Startup Disk Creator for a flash drive!  My last question (hopefully) is: How do I set the BIOS to boot from the USB drive?

Comment: I think that question would get a better response if you posted it on http://superuser.com. Tell them your motherboard make and model, and BIOS manufacturer (or as much as possible). Someone should be able to tell which keys to press to get the BIOS screen to appear.

Comment: So now I have a bootable flash drive; I did a test boot using it, and it seems to work.  I'm ready to install 14.04 LTS, but before I do I want to make sure that my Windows partition will be preserved intact (see my original question).  Will it?

Comment: If you don't manually erase it, it will not be erased...